# How to do counts in batch for graphql data loader?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, dataloader

I'm implementing a Graphql resolver for complex datatype. I try to use a data loader to avoid `N+1` problem. I have a datatype with a counter. Therefore, in one graphql query I need to perform user counting multiple times for different types. Currently, I'm trying to combine multiple `COUNT(*)` queries within one SQL query.

See the pseudo code:

```
# My type
type MyType {
  users_count: number
}

# The query returns an array of "MyType" 
getMyType(id: ID!): [MyType!]!

# Graphql query
getMyType(id: ID!) {
    id
    users_count
    created_at
}

# This is how I'm trying to do multiple counts
# 
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_with_users WHERE my_type_id = 1),
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_with_users WHERE my_type_id = 2)
```

The problem is I may have dozens of counts in one query. Is this going to be efficient for DB? What is the most efficient way of counting in this case?

Comment: The number of counts is not a problem. The size of table might be a problem. Or rather size of table per my_type_id (if indexed, it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A far more efficient way to do those multiple counts is to do it using a single **group by** query.

```
SELECT
  my_type_id
, COUNT(*) as count_of
FROM table_with_users 
WHERE my_type_id IN(1,2,3) -- adjust this detail as needed
GROUP BY
  my_type_id
```

This will produce 1 row per my_type_id.

If you absolutely must have just one row with many columns, then you can still achieve that with a single query:

```
SELECT
       COUNT(CASE WHEN my_type_id = 1 THEN 1 END) AS type_1
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN my_type_id = 2 THEN 1 END) AS type_2
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN my_type_id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS type_3
FROM table_with_users
WHERE my_type_id IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `table_with_users` index on `my_type_id`, doing multiple subselects should be just fine.

If you need to do a full table scan anyway (or have more complicated, possibly overlapping, conditions than just matching on `my_type_id`), it might be more efficient to use multiple `count` expressions in parallel, filtering for different rows:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE my_type_id = 1) AS count_of_type_1,
  COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE my_type_id = 2) AS count_of_type_2
FROM table_with_users
```

But if in doubt, [do a benchmark yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), and also try @PaulMaxwell's `GROUP BY` suggestion.